# Django: Two or more filters in django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to apply two filters in my django queryset

i am trying to do like

```
 get.archived:get_meetings = Meeting.objects.filter(created_by = user_id.id).filter(date_created__lte = datetime.date.today()[index:limit]
```

but i  am getting the syntax error .

I also tried `Q`   but here i couldn't find the and like statement or is there please help me how can i acheive  this in django

Comment: i think you are missing closing parenthesis at the end before `[index:limit]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the two filters together,

```
get_meetings = Meeting.objects.filter(created_by = user_id.id, date_created__lte = datetime.date.today())[index:limit]
```

Answer (score 3):

you are missing closing parenthesis `)` at the end after `datetime.date.today()`, this should work.

```
get_meetings = Meeting.objects.filter(created_by = user_id.id).filter(date_created__lte = datetime.date.today())[index:limit]
```